# log json payload BEFORE request

Tags: spring-boot, logging

In Spring Boot, one can log the request with `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter`.
With `setIncludePayload(true)` also the JSON payload of the request is included. But it seems to be that in this way, the JSON payload is only included in the AFTER MESSAGE. During the generation of the message printed in BEFORE MESSAGE, the content generation in `AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.createMessage` return an empty array for `byte[] buf = wrapper.getContentAsByteArray();`. As result, the request payload is printed after the request is processed which is very innatural.

How it is possible, to include the json payload in the log message written before the request is processed ?

Comment: Did you found any solution for this problem?

Comment: no, I use the mentioned version with payload in AFTER MESSAGE log, unusual but ok for me.

Comment: I didn't understood your comment.Could you be more specific?what is mentioned version.